# MySQL return only users in a specified group

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, group-concat

In MySql database I have a fairly common users and groups with a pivot users_groups to allow N:M relationships.

table `users`

```
id      | name
--------+----------
1       | Joe
2       | Anna
3       | Max
```

Table `groups`

```
id       | name
---------+----------
1        | Red
2        | Blue
3        | Green
```

Table `users_groups`

```
id       | userid | groupid
---------+--------+---------
1        | 1      | 2
2        | 3      | 2
3        | 1      | 3 
3        | 2      | 1
```

So... Member of the Red(1) group is Anna(2), member of the Green(3) group is Joe(1) and members of the Blue(2) group are Joe(1) and Max(3).

When a user is logged in, I have the user id (e.g. 1 for Joe) and I would like to lookup all the other users in a specific group that my logged in user is also a member of. How can I get the list of users in that group?

I need to lookup the group name using text supplied from a form and the userid will be obtained from the auth/login code.  If the user is not part of the group, they should not be able to get a list of the group members.

For Red group, I should only see one user (Anna) when logged in as Anna

```
User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
1     | Red   | EMPTY

User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
2     | Red   | Anna

User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
3     | Red   | EMPTY
```

And for Blue group, if I am logged in as Joe or Max then I should see a list of users (Joe and Max)

```
User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
1     | Blue  | Joe, Max

User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
2     | Blue  | EMPTY

User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
3     | Blue  | Joe, Max
```

For Green group, I should only see one user (Joe) when logged in as Joe

```
User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
1     | Green   | Joe

User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
2     | Green   | EMPTY

User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
3     | Green   | EMPTY
```

=== UPDATE #1 ===

Using @Erico's answer and the fiddle below with updated table schema to include enabled and email fields, I can do the following with additional `enabled` column checks.  However, I'd like to return all the Users as individual rows in the results set rather than a single `Users` column with all data in there.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80da98/2

```
SELECT '1' as User, name as Group,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email) FROM users u, users_groups ug 
 WHERE u.enabled = 1 AND u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = g.id AND ug.group_id 
 IN (SELECT group_id FROM users_groups WHERE user_id = 1)
) as Users
FROM groups g
 WHERE g.name = 'Blue' AND g.enabled = 1
```

=== UPDATE #2 ===

Instead of returning the results in a single row:

```
User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
1     | Blue  | Joe, Max
```

or using emails instead of names

```
User  | Group | Users in Group must include the current user
------+------------
1     | Blue  | joe@mycompany.com, max@hiscompany.com
```

I'd like to return the users full information in a row per user, thus searching as user Joe(1) in Group Blue(2) would return:

```
User  | Name  | Email
------+------------
1     | Joe   | joe@mycompany.com
3     | Max   | max@hiscompany.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with sub-queries that displays the results as shown in your question.

Joe showinng group Blue:

```
SELECT '1' as `User`, name as `Group`, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM users u, users_groups ug 
 WHERE u.id = ug.user_id AND ug.group_id = g.id 
 AND ug.group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM users_groups WHERE user_id = 1)
 ) as `Users` 
FROM groups g
 WHERE g.name = 'Blue'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a735/22/0

Comment: This worked a treat and thanks for the fiddle.  One more request - how would I return no rows if the match fails - currently there is always one row returned with either the correct user list or NULL.  If NULL returned in `Users` I'd like to return an empty set.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80da98

This fiddle is a bit more specific to my actual table design, I would also like to check an enabled flag for each user and each group and only return results for enabled user in enabled groups.  Also rather than the user names, I'd like to return the email addresses in the `Users` result column.  If I work it out myself, I'll post the answer.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80da98/8/0. just added enabled flag and moved user/group condition to the main query so no rows are returned when it doesn't match any groups.

Comment: One last thing then, how to return the users in a row per user rather than CONCAT'd in to one row? see update #2 on the original question.